# Single user for whole application?

Tags: jsf, tomcat, richfaces

In my application, JSF2.0, richfaces 3.3.3 and Tomcat.
I need, to prevent user multiple tabs in same browser.
Means, If the user login into the application, after that copying the url and paste into the other tab..that time i need to logout that user..

Help me...
Thanks inadvance.

Answer (score 1):

You can and should not. You can not, because it can never be achieved reliably. JavaScript can do a lot, but you're still dependent on whether the enduser has it enabled and or the browser can successfully fire a (XML)HTTP request before the unload event, which is really a race condition. You should not, because it would completely destroy the user experience and only result in "wtf?" experiences.

You need to fix the *real* underlying problem for which you thought that this would be the right solution. This smells too much like session scope abuse. In that case, take your time to go through [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope) You seem to really need the view scope instead.

Comment: lots of banking websites do it, presumably for security rather than just to irritate users.

Comment: @Damo: maybe you've worked with different banking sites than I've seen so far.

Comment: @Damo: thanks for your comment..if you have any idea about my question, help me.how to achieve this?